# How synchronization with SyncAdapter works on android?

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

If I need to start synchronization adhoc, I use `requestSync`. But looks like it doesn't work when `setIsSyncable` defined as `false`. How to initiate synchronization by user request in this case?

Moreover, if after that I define `setIsSyncable` as `true` and also start period syncs with `addPeriodicSync`, synchronization starts 2 times.

Comment: When you sync to the server, if a change comes in and you modify your local database to match, are you calling ContentResolver.notifyChange()?  if so, with what parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1:  **To override setIsSyncable:**

Add `ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_IGNORE_SETTINGS` set to `true` in the `requestSync()` extras Bundle.

2:  **Double-sync**

(see comment first)

Comment: Thanks. With regards to 2 - I do nothing with notifyChange currently.